# How to use constraints that apply to each type in a heterogenous collection?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I'm trying to figure out heterogenous collections, and there's some kind of a type-checking problem I can't wrap my head around.

```
data HTypeMap (f :: * -> *) (types :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HTypeMap f '[]
  HCons :: f e -> HTypeMap f types -> HTypeMap f (e ': types)
```

(It's basically supposed to be a map from types to values of that type, under some functor `f`). E.g.:

```
testMap :: HTypeMap Prelude.Maybe '[Prelude.Int, Prelude.String]
testMap = HCons (Prelude.Just 3) (HCons (Prelude.Just "Hello") HNil)
```

I've been trying to formulate a function that would allow me to run a `map` in case I know that all of the types in my collection are constrained, to be used like:

```
showEverything :: AllConstrained Show types => HTypeMap f types -> [String]
showEverything = mapConstrained show


type family AllConstrained (c :: u -> Constraint) (ts :: [u]) :: Constraint where
  AllConstrained c '[] = ()
  AllConstrained c (t ': ts) = (c t, AllConstrained c ts)
```

---

My attempts so far:

1. Just a simple function... GHC won't let me write this type:

```
mapConstrained :: AllConstrained c types => (forall t. c t => f t -> a) -> HTypeMap f types -> [a]
mapConstrained = _
```

It says:

```
• Could not deduce: AllConstrained c0 types
  from the context: AllConstrained c types
```

I don't understand this at all... I have only one constraint to be considered there, it's `c`. (I have `ScopedTypeVariables` on.)

Same goes for a typeclass in the same style... There's some kind of ambiguity here that I don't notice...

2.

This unwieldy one actually works:

```
data ContraintRunnerF f c r = ContraintRunnerF {runMeF :: forall x. c x => f x -> r}

class MapConstrained c types where
  mapConstrained :: forall a f r. AllConstrained c types => ContraintRunnerF f c r -> HTypeMap f types -> [r]

instance MapConstrained c '[] where
  mapConstrained _ HNil = []

instance MapConstrained c types => MapConstrained c (t ': types) where
  mapConstrained g (HCons e rest) = (runMeF g e) : mapConstrained @c g rest
```

used like:

```
showRunnerF :: ContraintRunnerF Prelude.Identity Prelude.Show Prelude.String
showRunnerF = ContraintRunnerF Prelude.show

showRunnerFM :: ContraintRunnerF Prelude.Maybe Prelude.Show Prelude.String
showRunnerFM = ContraintRunnerF Prelude.show

testMap :: HTypeMap Prelude.Maybe '[Prelude.Int, Prelude.String]
testMap = HCons (Prelude.Just 3) (HCons (Prelude.Just "Hello") HNil)

test1 :: [Prelude.String]
test1 = mapConstrained showRunnerFM testMap
```

but unfortunately even a simple substitution would not typecheck, basically requiring me to specify all the types:

```
test2 :: [Prelude.String]
test2 = mapConstrained (ContraintRunnerF Prelude.show) testMap

• Could not deduce: (c0 Prelude.Int, c0 [Prelude.Char])
    arising from a use of ‘mapConstrained’
```

---

So, questions:

1. How do I understand the problem GHC has with these approaches?
2. How do I go about making a function that would address my need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type variable `c` is called *ambiguous* in the type of `mapConstrained` because there is never any way to determine what that type variable should be from it's arguments.

The solution to this is `TypeApplications`, which allows you to explicitly specify a type for an ambiguous type variable.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Kind

data HTypeMap (f :: * -> *) (types :: [*]) where
  HNil :: HTypeMap f '[]
  HCons :: f e -> HTypeMap f types -> HTypeMap f (e ': types)

type family AllConstrained (c :: u -> Constraint) (ts :: [u]) :: Constraint where
  AllConstrained c '[] = ()
  AllConstrained c (t ': ts) = (c t, AllConstrained c ts)

mapConstrained :: AllConstrained c types => (forall t. c t => f t -> a) -> HTypeMap f types -> [a]
mapConstrained _ _  = undefined

testMap :: HTypeMap Prelude.Maybe '[Prelude.Int, Prelude.String]
testMap = HCons (Prelude.Just 3) (HCons (Prelude.Just "Hello") HNil)

-- Note here that `@Show' is the type application - it applies `mapConstrained' at the type level
test = mapConstrained @Show show testMap
```

You once again must specify the type variable explicitly in the second case:

```
test2 :: [Prelude.String]
test2 = mapConstrained (ContraintRunnerF @_ @Show Prelude.show) testMap
```

Comment: it works now with AllowAmbiguousTypes and the explicit application, thank you!